# android java opencv 2.4 convexhull convexdefect

Tags: java, android, opencv, convex-hull

**Open-CV 2.4 Android-Java:**

i have searched for contours (list of MatofPoint) like this:

```
Imgproc.findContours(roi_mat, contours, hierarchy, cfg.retMode, cfg.apxMode);
```

and then the convexhull **(has to be a list of MatofInt )**

```
for (int k=0; k < contours.size(); k++){

     Imgproc.convexHull(contours.get(k), hull.get(k));
}
```

*The convexhull wants a MatofInt but the drawcontours wants a MatofPoint.. So what to do?*

Thx in advance..

---

**Edit**: @OpenCV4Android

```
for (int k=0; k < contours.size(); k++){
    Imgproc.convexHull(contours.get(k), hullInt);

    for(int j=0; j < hullInt.toList().size(); j++){
        hullPointList.add(contours.get(k).toList().get(hullInt.toList().get(j)));
    }

    hullPointMat.fromList(hullPointList);
    hullPoints.add(hullPointMat);   
}

Imgproc.drawContours( mROI, hullPoints, -1,  new Scalar(255,0,0, 255), 1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like OpenCV Java API lacks another convexHull() signature:

```
convexHull(MatOfPoint points, MatOfPoint hull);
```

like it's possible to call in C++.

While we haven't added it, you need to create the **hull** in **MatOfPoint** format manually:

- use `MatOfPoint::toArray()` or `MatOfPoint::toList()` to get contour's points
- use `MatOfInt::toArray()` or `MatOfInt::toList()` to get their indexes for hull
- create a new `Point[]` or `List<Point>` with hull's points only
- convert it to `MatOfPoint` via `MatOfPoint::fromArray()` or `MatOfPoint::fromList()`
- call `Core.drawContours()`

Comment: well i've tried it like this (edit in question):
i'm not sure if its totally right cause i don't get good results.. most of the time there are just a lot of red convex hull lines crossing the img..

Comment: or is this because of the findcontour (i tried a canny and or threshold and gauss filter before findcontour)

Answer (score 0):

we need **clear hullPointList** before add list point for a contour

```
hullPointList .clear();
for(int j=0; j < hullInt.toList().size(); j++){
        hullPointList.add(contours.get(k).toList().get(hullInt.toList().get(j)));
    }
```