# Convex Hull on Java Android Opencv 2.3

Tags: java, android, opencv, convex-hull

Please help me,

I have a problem for Convex Hull on Android. I use Java and **OpenCV 2.3**.

Before I made it on Java, I made it on C++ with Visual Studio 2008.

This code can running successfully on C++.

Now, i want to convert it from C++ to Java on Android. And I found error like "force close" when i run it on SDK Android simulator.

This is my code on C++:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_64F );

/// Find the convex hull object for each contour
vector<vector<Point> > hull ( contours.size() );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
  {  convexHull( Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false );
}

for(size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
    drawContours( drawing, hull, i, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED ); // FILL WHITE COLOR
}
```

And this is my code on Android:

```
Mat hierarchy = new Mat(img_canny.rows(),img_canny.cols(),CvType.CV_8UC1,new Scalar(0));
    List<Mat> contours =new ArrayList<Mat>();
    List<Mat> hull = new ArrayList<Mat>(contours.size());
    drawing = Mat.zeros(img_canny.size(), im_gray);

    Imgproc.findContours(img_dilasi, contours, hierarchy,Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0, 0));

    for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++){
        Imgproc.convexHull(contours.get(i), hull.get(i), false);

    }
    for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++){
        Imgproc.drawContours(drawing, hull, i, new Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0), 5);
    }
```

For your info, I did a little modification on Convex Hull at my code. **I fill a color inside contour**.

Anyone can help me to solve my problem?

I'm very grateful for your help.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is causing your problem. What is the specific error you get? Is there log output related to it?

Comment: When I run it on SDK Android Simulator, the windows error appeared, "the application stoped unexpectedly" and I was told to stop by click "Force Close".

And when I checked on Log Cat error Eclipse, I found that process stop on this line "Imgproc.convexHull(contours.get(i), hull.get(i), false);"


I don't know why the process stoped on that line. 

Can't you help explain to me?

Comment: I think I made ​​a mistake when declaring "hull" variable. 

But, I don't know how to solve that problem. I think I have declared that variable in accordance with the applicable provisions.

What about your opinion? 
Do you think that the declaration of a variable "hull" in my code isn't correct?

Comment: Did any of the posted answers solve your problem? If so, would you [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) one of them? If not, please leave a comment stating what we can improve.

Answer (score 10):

Don't have the rep to add comment, just wanted to say the two answers above helped me get Imgproc.convexHull() working for my use case with something like this (2.4.8):

```
MatOfPoint mopIn = ...
MatOfInt hull = new MatOfInt();
Imgproc.convexHull(mopIn, hull, false);

MatOfPoint mopOut = new MatOfPoint();
mopOut.create((int)hull.size().height,1,CvType.CV_32SC2);

for(int i = 0; i < hull.size().height ; i++)
{
    int index = (int)hull.get(i, 0)[0];
    double[] point = new double[] {
        mopIn.get(index, 0)[0], mopIn.get(index, 0)[1]
    };
    mopOut.put(i, 0, point);
}           
// do something interesting with mopOut
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works well in my application. In my case, I had multiple contours to work with, so you will notice a lot of Lists, but if you only have one contour, just adjust it to work without the .get(i) iterations.

This thread explains the process more simply.

[android java opencv 2.4 convexhull convexdefect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961660/android-java-opencv-2-4-convexhull-convexdefect#answer-10962281)

```
   // Find the convex hull
            List<MatOfInt> hull = new ArrayList<MatOfInt>();
            for(int i=0; i < contours.size(); i++){
                hull.add(new MatOfInt());
            }
            for(int i=0; i < contours.size(); i++){
                Imgproc.convexHull(contours.get(i), hull.get(i));
            }

            // Convert MatOfInt to MatOfPoint for drawing convex hull

            // Loop over all contours
            List<Point[]> hullpoints = new ArrayList<Point[]>();
            for(int i=0; i < hull.size(); i++){
                Point[] points = new Point[hull.get(i).rows()];

                // Loop over all points that need to be hulled in current contour
                for(int j=0; j < hull.get(i).rows(); j++){
                    int index = (int)hull.get(i).get(j, 0)[0];
                    points[j] = new Point(contours.get(i).get(index, 0)[0], contours.get(i).get(index, 0)[1]);
                }

                hullpoints.add(points);
            }

            // Convert Point arrays into MatOfPoint
            List<MatOfPoint> hullmop = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            for(int i=0; i < hullpoints.size(); i++){
                MatOfPoint mop = new MatOfPoint();
                mop.fromArray(hullpoints.get(i));
                hullmop.add(mop);
            }


            // Draw contours + hull results
            Mat overlay = new Mat(binaryImage.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
            Scalar color = new Scalar(0, 255, 0);   // Green
            for(int i=0; i < contours.size(); i++){
                Imgproc.drawContours(overlay, contours, i, color);
                Imgproc.drawContours(overlay, hullmop, i, color);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example in Java (OpenCV 2.4.11)**

`hullMat` contains the sub mat of `gray`, as identified by the `convexHull` method. 
You may want to filter the contours you really need, for example based on their area.

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
MatOfInt4 hierarchy = new MatOfInt4();
MatOfInt hull = new MatOfInt();

void foo(Mat gray) {
    Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);        
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Imgproc.convexHull(contours.get(i), hull);
        MatOfPoint hullContour = hull2Points(hull, contours.get(i));
        Rect box = Imgproc.boundingRect(hullContour);
        Mat hullMat = new Mat(gray, box);
        ...
    }
}

MatOfPoint hull2Points(MatOfInt hull, MatOfPoint contour) {
    List<Integer> indexes = hull.toList();
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    MatOfPoint point= new MatOfPoint();
    for(Integer index:indexes) {
        points.add(contour.toList().get(index));
    }
    point.fromList(points);
    return point;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation of [`findContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#findContours%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20java.util.List,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int%29) and [`convexHull()`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#convexHull%28org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfInt%29), it appears that you have declared the variables `contours` and `hull` incorrectly.

Try changing the declarations to:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
List<MatOfInt> hull = new ArrayList<MatOfInt>();
```

Then, after you call `convexHull()`, `hull` contains the *indices* of the points in `contours` which comprise the convex hull. In order to draw the points with `drawContours()`, you will need to populate a new `MatOfPoint` containing only the points on the convex hull, and pass that to `drawContours()`. I leave this as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to what Aurelius said, in your C++ implementation you used a vector of points, therefore the hull matrix contains the actual convex Points:

> "In the first case [integer vector of indices], the hull elements are 0-based indices of the convex hull points in the original array (since the set of convex hull points is a subset of the original point set). In the second case [vector of points], hull elements are the convex hull points themselves." - [convexHull](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexhull)

This is why you were able to call

```
drawContours( drawing, hull, i, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED );
```

In your android version, the hull output is simply an array of indices which correspond to the points in the original contours.get(i) Matrix. Therefore you need to look up the convex points in the original matrix. Here is a very rough idea:

```
MatOfInt hull = new MatOfInt();
MatOfPoint tempContour = contours.get(i);
Imgproc.convexHull(tempContour, hull, false); // O(N*Log(N))
//System.out.println("hull size: " + hull.size() + " x" + hull.get(0,0).length);
//System.out.println("Contour matrix size: " + tempContour.size() + " x" + tempContour.get(0,0).length);

int index = (int) hull.get(((int) hull.size().height)-1, 0)[0];
Point pt, pt0 = new Point(tempContour.get(index, 0)[0], tempContour.get(index, 0)[1]);
for(int j = 0; j < hull.size().height -1 ; j++){
    index = (int) hull.get(j, 0)[0];
    pt = new Point(tempContour.get(index, 0)[0], tempContour.get(index, 0)[1]);
    Core.line(frame, pt0, pt, new Scalar(255, 0, 100), 8);
    pt0 = pt;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this `fillconvexPoly`

```
 for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ){
          Imgproc.fillConvexPoly(image_2, point,new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    }
```