# Convert MatOfInt to MatofPoint

Tags: java, opencv

I am pretty new to OpenCV, and am using a Java wrapper of OpenCV. In my application I am detecting contours and then making convexHull around it. Imgproc.convexHell(matofpoint, matofint); provides me with hull values in MatOfInt form.

Now I wanna print matofint in my image, but the Imgproc. drawContour() require MatOfPoint.

So my question is how to convert MatOfInt to MatOfPoint

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convex Hull on Java Android Opencv 2.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586948/convex-hull-on-java-android-opencv-2-3)

Comment: Take a look at the second part of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17618897/1601291) answer. It should explain your issue.

Comment: Tried everything,but none is working!!! :o

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question with (minimal) code demonstrating what you have tried. That way people can see what you've done, and correct errors you may have made.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static MatOfPoint convertIndexesToPoints(MatOfPoint contour, MatOfInt indexes) {
    int[] arrIndex = indexes.toArray();
    Point[] arrContour = contour.toArray();
    Point[] arrPoints = new Point[arrIndex.length];

    for (int i=0;i<arrIndex.length;i++) {
        arrPoints[i] = arrContour[arrIndex[i]];
    }

    MatOfPoint hull = new MatOfPoint(); 
    hull.fromArray(arrPoints);
    return hull; 
}
```