# How to get the largest value from ArrayList<MatOfPoint>?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, arraylist

For starters, I'm trying to draw contours and convexhull on matrix in OpenCV Android. I followed [these codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28040295/4160222) to my program shown like this:

```
/// Start contourImg
    Log.i(TAG, "called contourImg");

//init
    List<MatOfInt> hull         = new ArrayList<MatOfInt>();
    List<Point[]> hullPoints    = new ArrayList<Point[]>();
    List<MatOfPoint> hullMOP    = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    List<MatOfPoint> contours   = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat overlay     = input.clone();
    Mat hierarchy   = new Mat(mask.rows(), mask.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
    Point titik1    = new Point(0,0);
            
    Imgproc.findContours(mask, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, titik1);
            
//Find the convex hull
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        hull.add(new MatOfInt());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Imgproc.convexHull(contours.get(i), hull.get(i), false);
    }
            
// Convert MatOfInt to MatOfPoint for drawing convex hull
            
// Loop over all contours   
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Point[] points = new Point[hull.get(i).rows()];
                
    // Loop over all points that need to be hulled in current contour
        for (int j = 0; j < hull.get(i).rows(); j++) {
            int index = (int) hull.get(i).get(j,  0)[0];
            points[j] = new Point(contours.get(i).get(index, 0)[0], contours.get(i).get(index, 0)[1]);
        }
        hullPoints.add(points);
    }
            
// Convert Point arrays into MatOfPoint
    for (int i = 0; i < hullPoints.size(); i++) {
        MatOfPoint mop = new MatOfPoint();
        mop.fromArray(hullPoints.get(i));
        hullMOP.add(mop);
    }
            
// Draw contours + hull results
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Imgproc.drawContours(overlay, contours, i, green);
        Imgproc.drawContours(overlay, hullMOP, i, red); 
    }
```

Basically, the output will draw the obtained contours and convexhulls in green and red respectively. Unfortunately, the drawing becomes too absurd that small contours and convexhulls are being drawn as well.

> Edit: this is image example. Notice the smaller red and green regions those are also appeared, while I want them not to appear.
>
> [image: convexhull image example]

The question is: how should I manipulate the `hullMOP` arraylist so that I get the index pointing to `MatOfPoint` with only consists of largest contours and convexhull? I tried to apply the same thinking as `Imgproc.boundingRect()` method by try finding the largest area (as follows):

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    boundRect[i] = Imgproc.boundingRect(polyMOP.get(i));
}
Rect bigRect = new Rect();
for (int i = 0; i < boundRect.length; i++) {
    if (bigRect.area() < boundRect[i].area()) {
        bigRect = boundRect[i];
    }
}
Core.rectangle(image3, bigRect.tl(), bigRect.br(), green, 2);
```

, but I can't get any hit. Any advice will help. Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if it's a little bit too late.

I think you can use `Imgproc.contourArea` to check the largest area of both `hullMOP` and `contours`.

Here is an example:

```
Mat maxContour = null;
double maxContourarea=0;
for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
    Mat contour = contours.get(idx);
    double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
    if (contourarea > maxContourarea){
        maxContourarea = contourarea;
        maxContour = contour;
    }
}
```

and hence `maxContour` will contain the largest contour with `maxContourarea` is the area value.

Answer (score 0):

You  can use `Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL`. 
**`CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`** retrieves only the extreme outer contours. It sets `hierarchy[i][2]=hierarchy[i][3]=-1` for all the contours.
In other words, use `Imgproc.findContours(mask, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, titik1)`.