# How to create a convex hull of all binary spots in ImageJ

Tags: image-processing, imagej, binary-image, fiji

I have a binary image of separated spots.

[image: Source binary image of sports]

Is there any ImageJ plugin that could construct convex hull of all spots?

Or could you recommend another program, not ImageJ, that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

With OpenCV you can use findContours() and then convexHull()

You can see a complete example here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html

OpenCV is a library, which means that you have to code the program yourself. It has bindings for Java, python and many other languages. You can easily find the same example in other languages:

[Convex Hull on Java Android Opencv 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586948/convex-hull-on-java-android-opencv-2-3)

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have an 8-bit (binary) image in ImageJ, you can run the following Groovy script from the [script editor](https://imagej.net/Using_the_Script_Editor) to get the convex hull as current selection:

```groovy
#@ ImagePlus imp

import ij.gui.PolygonRoi
import ij.gui.Roi
import ij.plugin.filter.ThresholdToSelection
import ij.process.ImageProcessor

imp.getProcessor().setThreshold(128,255,ImageProcessor.NO_LUT_UPDATE)
roi = ThresholdToSelection.run(imp)
proi = new PolygonRoi(roi.getContainedFloatPoints(), Roi.POLYGON)
chRoi = new PolygonRoi(proi.getConvexHull(), Roi.POLYGON)
imp.setRoi(chRoi)
```

Note that in general, this type of question might be considered off-topic here and is better asked on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/), where you'll get advice from image processing experts.

Comment: Thank you, I've written my own script.

Comment: @IvanZ would you mind sharing how you solved it in the end? Maybe as a new answer to this question? I'd be interested to see how others tackle this.

Comment: For others interested in this topic: see also [this ImageJ forum discussion](http://forum.imagej.net/t/merge-rois-into-one-big-one-bounding-n-polyline/9742?u=imagejan) for related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit-Selection-make selection, then ConvexHull