# convexity defects coordinates java android

Tags: java, android, opencv, coordinates, convex-hull

How can access coordinates of convexity defects and convexhull?

I try to do measurment of each finger (on open-palm hand picture) and i would like to get acces to coordinates first five points of convexhull and first four points of convexity defects (counting from the top of an image). To do that, i need to know what the coorginates (x and y) are.

The format od convexhull is MatOfInt and the format of convexityDefects is MatOfInt4.
I was looking for answer but unfortunately only answer I found was in C++, and I'm working with java.

I will be very gratefull for any help.

Comment: This answer is helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961660/android-java-opencv-2-4-convexhull-convexdefect

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting your MatOfInt to a List of Point's ?

You can do it like this:

```
// MatOfInt mat;
List<Point> list1 = mat.toList();   

// Or:
List<Point> list2 = new ArrayList<Point>();

Converters.Mat_to_vector_Point(mat, list2);
```

You can find more OpenCV Java data structure converters [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/utils/Converters.html).